# zend error handling for Web Services

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework

I have a question regarding error handling in Zend. I am fairly new to zend frame work.

I am new on this project that i am working on and the previous developers didn't handle service errors and the application is fairly large so I am trying to figure out an easy way to handle all the errors the service returns, and even handle the errors when service fails.
so when ever there is an error we need to alert the user that something is wrong and show the error.

now since i will be getting that in Model, how do I handle this in elegant way so that there is not much rework to be done.

Can i create a common class and extend it? I also need to alert the user in case of any error.
I want a better way because I have more than 150 controller files and about more than 100 model files.

Thanks

Comment: Throw an exception and handle it in your error controller

Comment: @Phil Agreed, that's what I was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

For a ZF app that's using `Zend_Application`, you should ensure that your `application.ini` file has this in it:

```
resources.frontController.throwExceptions = false
```

Then any Exception that is thrown will be trapped and the `ErrorController`'s `errorAction()` method will be called. This gives you a centralised place to handle errors.